# npm install output all logs to standard error stream

Tags: node.js, npm

I was trying to log things properly including the way the npm install is being executed. But npm is logging all its logs to error stream so my app logging capability is always showing that these logs are error but are not. Is there a way to set npm to use console.log instead of console.error?

Answer (score 0):

Use npm programatically, so that you can override the default error handler. As seen in [Readme](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/README.html) and [in source of npm cli interface](https://github.com/npm/npm/blob/master/bin/npm-cli.js):

```
var npm = require('npm');
(...)
// now actually fire up npm and run the command.
// this is how to use npm programmatically:
npm.load(conf, function (er) {
  if (er) return errorHandler(er)
  npm.commands[npm.command](npm.argv, errorHandler)
})
```